# Using boost python in an Rcpp package build on windows

Tags: python, boost, g++, rcpp

I am building an Rcpp package (on a windows OS) where I want to use boost python to call python code.

How do I set the correct include path in the "Makevars" file or is it possible to use the BH package (http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-boost-with-bh/) for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

This may not work on Windows -- see [the post on embedding Python in R via Rcpp and Boost.Python](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-python/) which pretty clearly states that many of the settings are tested only on Ubuntu.

You would have to make sure that R, Rcpp, Python, Boost.Python, ... are all built consistently, and on Windows things usually go down south when you try mix C++ code from `g++` (like R and Rcpp) with code from VC++ (like Boost).

If you were to build everything from source, maybe.   Or just use a virtual machine, or container, and run it in Ubuntu.  Setting up Docker is not hard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any plans to include a boost::python wrapper in BH ?

Comment: As we explain pretty clearly, BH is header-only, and Boost.Python is not. So no.

Comment: Since the compilation of a Rcpp package is triggered on installing the package, a package build on a Linux distribution can only be installed and used on a Linux distribution, i.e. there is no platform independence. Right?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  Are you hoping to build on Linux and run on Windows?  That will not work (unless for very special cases of cross-compilers).